# Error : a 'for each' statement cannot operate on an expression of type "MyKinect::ActionKeys []"

Tags: c++, foreach, find, key, stdmap

I'm very new to c# and c++. I want to convert C# code into C++ but I have an error on `for each (auto key in keys)`. Would you mind telling me what I am doing wrong. Many thanks.

C# code :

```
Public InputResule GetKey(ActionKeys[] keys)
    {
        InputResule ir = new InputResule();

        foreach (var key in keys)
        {
            var data = mActionList.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Key == key);
            if (data.Value != MovementType.None)
            {
                ir = CheckMovement(data.Value);
            }
        }
        return ir;
    }
```

C++ Code :

```
InputResule KinectInput::GetKey(ActionKeys keys[])
{
    InputResule ir = InputResule();

for each (auto key in keys)
    {
        auto data = mActionList.find(key->first);
        {
            return p->Key == key;
        };
        if (data->Value != MovementType::None)
        {
            ir = CheckMovement(data->Value);
        }
    }
    return ir;
}
```

Comment: There is no `for each` statement in C++

Comment: Tx mike, if i replace the for each statement to this -> for (auto it = mActionList.begin(); it != mActionList.end(); ++it) ; is it correct if i want to achieve the same result as in c#? Becuz currently It gives me 2 errors, "key" and "p" identifier is undefined.

Comment: That looks like a legal `for` statement for iterating over elements of
a Standard Library container type. The body of the loop remains broken by coding goofs, but with all due respect, SO is not is a resource for free elementary tuition in C++. That's why you have no answers. Knuckle down and learn the language and you'll be welcome back here when you have genuine programming problems.

Comment: Sure, txvm for the help..